# Jenkins: git SCM poll for only new branches matching certain regex

Tags: jenkins, version-control, polling

Is there a way to just poll for if a new branch matching a regex is created?

For example, if a branch matching: `release-v<version>` is created, then do something.

Examples of valid branches:

```
release-v1
release-v2
release-v4
release-v123
```

Comment: Do you want to explicitly check whether the branch was newly created?

Comment: @ycr I just want to check for any new branches match that regex. If a new branch is found, then do something

regex: ^(systembuild-[0-9]+.x)

Comment: @Alphie so did you get a solution for this yet?